# How to achieve smooth scroll like google home tv application

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I am using `TvLazyColumn` to render multiple rows and `TvLazyRow` to render multiple items inside each row. I am able to render data however the app crashes sometimes when user scrolls fast using DPAD_DOWN or DPAD_UP keys. The errors are

`- java.lang.IllegalStateException: visitAncestors called on an unattached node`

`- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Place was called on a node which was placed already`

Also focus on item moves very fast than actual scroll position.

I am looking for a solution with which I can achieve scroll like what we can see on google home tab.

Comment: There is an existing bug regarding the crash: [b/312677265](https://issuetracker.google.com/312677265). For fast scrolling issues, checkout the performance FAQs in the [TV compose developer guide](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:tv/onboarding.md).

Comment: Thanks @vighnesh153, will check alternative here

Comment: @vighnesh153 can you please help to explain, how google tv managing fast smooth scroll, there animation recomposition to smooth and focus management as well curious to understand tried a lots for achieving similar like effect but unfortunately didn't succeeded yet.